# Can't configure Jackson mix in

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Could you please help me to configure correctly *Jackson* mix-in annotation with *Spring MVC* to customize a *JSON* response.

This is what I have now :

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
```

I don't know how to configure it to map the 2 classes ... : `addMixInAnnotations(User.class, UserMixIn.class);`

Answer (score 2):

dd the mixin configuration to the `ObjectMapper` once initialized in your `Controller` constructor:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public MyController(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(User.class, UserMixIn.class);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/some-path")
    @ResponseBody
    public String someMethod()  {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(); // Mock List to hold your Users
        users.add(new User()); // Keep adding some users
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(users, new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
    }
}
```

And check out the output :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by @tmarwen will work just fine if you only need to configure the Mixin for a single controller.

However if you want to use the mixin thoughout all Spring controllers you need implement an approach similar to the following:

Change your XML configuration to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="objectMapper" ref="mapper"/>
</bean>
```

Next you need to configure the `mapper` bean that is referenced in the XML above. You could easily do that in XML with the use of SpEL and FactoryBean, but there is no good reason to do so when you have a great and super easy to use alternative in Java Config.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

   @Bean
   public ObjectMapper mapper() {
      final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.addMixInAnnotations(User.class, UserMixIn.class);
      return mapper; 
   }  
}
```

With the changes above in place, you need absolutely no reference to `ObjectMapper` in your controllers and can use Spring MVC's JSON features just like you are using them now.

Comment: Could always use a `FactoryBean` in XML.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Spot on as always!! But you would also need to get hold of the `Class` which sort of complicates things just a bit. That is why is just went with Java Config. In my mind it's just so much more intuitive in most cases